# Function not being called on form submit, only blank admin-post.php page

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, oop

We are trying to call the function `on_save_settings` when the form with action `settings_form` is submitted.

But when we submit the form we only get a blank page with url `/wp-admin/admin-post.php`.

Here is the code we are using;

```
<?php
namespace WC_Portal\Admin;

/**
 * Settings page
 * @package    WC_Portal
 * @subpackage WC_Portal\Admin
 */

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

class Settings {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_post_nopriv_settings_form', array( $this, 'on_save_settings'));
        add_action('admin_post_settings_form', array( $this, 'on_save_settings'));    // Save any changes
    } 

    public static function index() {
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="settings_form">
                <label>API Token</label>
                <input type="text" name="api_token">
                <?php wp_nonce_field('ms_settings_form', 'ms_nonce'); ?>
                <?php echo get_submit_button('Speichern'); ?>
        </form>
        <?php
    }

    public function on_save_settings(){
        echo 'test';
  }

}
```

Does someone know why the function is not being called?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Where are you instantiating that class?

Comment: @bosco; `autoload.php` -> `includes/class-run.php` -> `includes/admin/class-pages.php`

There is class `includes/admin/class-settings.php` being called.